# Tkinter: when clicking on button GUI is frozen

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new using Tkinter to create GUIs. I would like to create a GUI which has a button that when pressed it executes some command lines.

This is the code for creating the button:

```
ros_start_button = Button(bottom_frame, text="Start ROS", command=self.start_ROS)
ros_start_button.pack(side=LEFT)
```

the code fro `self.start_ROS` is

```
def start_ROS(self):
    os.system("bash start_ROS.sh")
```

where start_ROS.sh is an sh file which code is:
echo "Starting ROS";

```
cd;
source /home/m/PycharmProjects/ROSAutonomousFlight/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash;
roslaunch ardrone_numeric_method_controller ardrone.launch;
```

When I press the button it is like the GUI is frozen until I stop the process that is executed by roslaunch .... I would like to know what can I do in order to just press the button, but not get the GUI frozen because I have other buttons that have to be pressed after this button.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The program is waiting for os.system("bash start_ROS.sh") to finish.  One of the things you can do is run it in the background --> os.system("bash start_ROS.sh &") Note the"&"  See http://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-run-commands-background-nohup-disown

Comment: @CurlyJoe How to do a similar thing in windows environment? Any ideas?